# Can I prevent iOS Simulator from changing the guid of my application while building?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I use the latest version of Visual Studio 2019,  Xamarin.iOS, MacOS, and XCode. When I build for iOS Simulator, the guid of my app always changes.

In this format {guid2} changes:
/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{guid1}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{guid2}

(A new folder is not created, it's just renamed.)

Is there a way to stop this?